# Different Header Image for Wordpress on Mobile and Desktop (Wordpress Theme Apostrophe 2)

Tags: wordpress

So I use Apostrophe 2 as my theme for my wordpress (asiklibur.com), I like the header image on mobile, but on the desktop it looks so bad because my logo (edited to header image) got cropped. can you guys tell me how I can use different header image on mobile and desktop?

because I'm still new with all of this, all I have try are trying to edit the image instead of do some code

Comment: if your image is coming through background image, then write a media query for desktop and write a property on header that will show different image. if not background image, then tell me how it's coming or share the url.

Comment: Depending on your level of knowledge you could use media queries and hide the display property of the div containing the image, but it sounds like you're using wordpress in an off the peg way and don't particularly want to get into editing the code